# jQuery add the values of all the option values

Tags: jquery

I have a markup like this

```
<select name="first_group" id="first_group" class="persons">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>                
</select>


<select name="second_group" id="second_group" class="persons">
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>              
</select>

<select name="third_group" id="third_group" class="persons">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>                
</select>
```

Here you can see I have 3 sections of options group, they are `first_group`, `second_group`, `third_group`
Now I want that when I make click on the `first_group` and select one value lets say 4 then the values for the second_group and the `third_group` selected value should be added with that. So in this way a total of 
`first_group`, `second_group` and `third_group` will be shown at the last.

For that I have made my code like this

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('body').on('change','.persons', function() {
        var Total = $(this).val();
        console.log(Total);
    });
});
```

But this one is showing the value of selected which has been selected. I want to add all those values even they are not selected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through each element and then add the values of each item

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('body').on('change', '.persons', function () {
        var total = 0;
        $('.persons').each(function () {
            total += +this.value || 0
        })
        console.log(total);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tcw0zs9v/)

Answer (score 0):

This way you can sum your select values :

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('body').on('change', '.persons', function () {
        var total = [];
        $('.persons').each(function () {
            total.push($(this).val());
        });
        
      var sum = eval(total.join("+"));
      alert("Total : " + sum);
      console.log(sum);
      
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="first_group" id="first_group" class="persons">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>                
</select>


<select name="second_group" id="second_group" class="persons">
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>              
</select>

<select name="third_group" id="third_group" class="persons">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>                
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also loop on just the selected options:

```
$('body').on('change', '.persons', function () {
    var total = 0;
    $('.persons option:selected').each(function () {
        total += Number(this.value)
    });
    console.log(total);
});
```